# More on Python TKinter Dynamic OptionMenu

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm trying to modify the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252096/python-tkinter-dynamic-optionmenu) to have the user confirm the items selected from the `optionmenus`. If the user clicks on the Submit button, a message box should open prompting confirmation. Finally, I want the selected items to be returned to the program as variables so they can be used in other functions for further processing. However, my modification is not working; it just returns an empty window. Thoughts on what I am missing? Many thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.dict = {'Asia': ['Japan', 'China', 'Malasia'],
                     'Europe': ['Germany', 'France', 'Switzerland'],
                     'Africa': ['Nigeria', 'Kenya', 'Ethiopia']}
        self.variable_a = StringVar(self)
        self.variable_b = StringVar(self)
        self.variable_a.trace('w', self.updateoptions)
        self.optionmenu_a = OptionMenu(self, self.variable_a, *self.dict.keys())
        self.variable_a.set('Asia')
        self.optionmenu_a.pack()
        self.optionmenu_b = OptionMenu(self, self.variable_b, ())
        self.optionmenu_b.pack()
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Submit", width=8, command=self.submit)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.pack()

    def updateoptions(self, *args):
        countries = self.dict[self.variable_a.get()]
        self.variable_b.set(countries[0])
        menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
        for country in countries:
            menu.add_command(label=country, command=lambda country=country: self.variable_b.set(country))
    
    def submit(self, *args):
        var1 = self.variable_a.get()
        var2 = self.variable_b.get()
        if tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Selection", "Confirm selection: " + var1 + ' ' + var2):
            print(var1, var2) #Or can be other function for further processing
         

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

**Python version 3.4.1**

EDIT: The window now appears with the widgets. I had omitted `self.` in front of the button. I still get an error message which I am trying to sort out: AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'optionmenu_b'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here @sedeh, this works as you wanted it to. The error came not from your add ons, but I think from using `from tkinter import *` instead of `import tkinter as tk`, this is why when running your code the error comes up as soon as the tk window comes up.

What I have done is taken the code from the link you gave, added what you did and it works with no error.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.dict = {'Asia': ['Japan', 'China', 'Malasia'],
                     'Europe': ['Germany', 'France', 'Switzerland'],
                     'Africa': ['Nigeria', 'Kenya', 'Ethiopia']}
        self.variable_a = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_b = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_a.trace('w', self.updateoptions)
        self.optionmenu_a = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_a, *self.dict.keys())
        self.optionmenu_b = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_b, '')
        self.variable_a.set('Asia')
        self.optionmenu_a.pack()
        self.optionmenu_b.pack()
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=8, command=self.submit)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.pack()
    def updateoptions(self, *args):
        countries = self.dict[self.variable_a.get()]
        self.variable_b.set(countries[0])
        menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
        for country in countries:
            menu.add_command(label=country, command=lambda country=country: self.variable_b.set(country))

    def submit(self, *args):
        var1 = self.variable_a.get()
        var2 = self.variable_b.get()
        if tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Selection", "Confirm selection: " + var1 + ' ' + var2):
            print(var1, var2) #Or can be other function for further processing

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am able to resize the window but having trouble moving the widgets around or coloring them. Any suggestions? Please see the modified code [here](http://ideone.com/KrezSo).

Comment: Ok, ill try to get onto it later, glad the rest helped.

Comment: Don't worry. I should be able to resize the window now. If you get a moment, please check out a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216135/more-on-tkinter-optionmenu-first-option-vanishes). The AttributeError reappeared again even though I am using `import tkinter as tk.`