# tkinter option menu - update options on fly

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI using Tkinter with Python 2.7.6.

I have a drop down menu, created and initially disabled with the following code:

```
    self.dropdown = Tkinter.OptionMenu(self, self.dropdownVar, "Select SED...")
    self.dropdown.grid(column=0,row=1)
    self.dropdown.configure(state="disabled")
```

After a user selects a directory, I call a function `onEnterDir()` which then gets a list of files in that directory. So, I have a list of files in a variable called `dirFiles`.

What I want is to then update the options in the dropdown menu with the items in this `dirFiles` list. How would I do this?

My question is different to others on here because I just want to update the list of items `self.dropdown` displays. It's not dependent on any other widget. I have a python list of things I want to put in. How do I do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate!

Comment: I believe you're referencing the wrong link. The old answer for your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17252390/400286

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same technique in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252096/python-tkinter-dynamic-optionmenu/17252390#17252390) you mentioned in question:

For example:

```
import os
from functools import partial
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

def onEnterDir(dropdown, var):
    path = askdirectory()
    if not path:
        return
    filenames = os.listdir(path)
    dropdown.configure(state='normal')  # Enable drop down
    menu = dropdown['menu']

    # Clear the menu.
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
    for name in filenames:
        # Add menu items.
        menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda name=name: var.set(name))
        # OR menu.add_command(label=name, command=partial(var.set, name))


root = Tk()
dropdownVar = StringVar()
dropdown = OptionMenu(root, dropdownVar, "Select SED...")
dropdown.grid(column=0, row=1)
dropdown.configure(state="disabled")
b = Button(root, text='Change directory',
           command=lambda: onEnterDir(dropdown, dropdownVar))
b.grid(column=1, row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why in the GUI, created by this code, just that the last item can be selected?

Comment: @R.GholizadehR., I don't get it.

Comment: @ falsetru, actually, when a directory is selected, its content is shown in the option menu but selection does not work. e.g. there are 10 items in the option menu; if you select the second item, the option menu shows the 10th item and it is locked there.

Comment: @R.GholizadehR., Ah, there was a bug; Replace `menu.add_command` line. I just updated the command accordingly; before the update, `name` in the lambda referenced the last `name` value (cause).

Answer (score 0):

Have to set self.dropdown to an active state first, and then put in the list of options like this:

```
    self.dropdown.configure(state="active")
    for fi in dirList:
        self.dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=fi, command=Tkinter._setit(self, fi))
```

The command bit was what was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

You have `OptionMenu.set_menu(*values)`, which does the similar things in @falsetru 's answer.

Comment: To get this to work I had to edit set_menu() in ttk.py because the keyword default argument was before the *list of positional arguments, so it was consuming the first item of the *list.