# Python Tkinter Dropdown menu that changes based on the previous variable chosen

Tags: python, tkinter, dropdown

I am trying to make a python program in tkinter that has 3 drop down menus. The values of the second and 3rd menu need to change based on the value chosen on the first menu. For example:

menu1= [1 , 2]

if 1 is chosen:

menu2 = [2 , 3]

if 2 is chosen:

menu2 = [4, 5]

I hope this makes since and as always thank you for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change OptionMenu based on what is selected in another OptionMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252096/change-optionmenu-based-on-what-is-selected-in-another-optionmenu)

Comment: Kind of. But how would this work in a context where you have 3 drop down menus instead of two?

Comment: The same, option 2 provides the value for the third `Optionmenu` and so on ...

Comment: self.dict = {'Asia': ['Japan', 'China', 'Malaysia'],
                     'Europe': ['Germany', 'France', 'Switzerland']}
So i would add another element to this dict or would i make a new dict?

Comment: for example {'North America': ['usa': [alabama, kansas] 'canada':[alberta, quebec]]}

Comment: Or am i doing it wrong..?

Comment: ***"Or am i doing it wrong..?***: Yes, don't comment code, [edit] your question instead and move it into the question.