Tkinter linked combobox populate by MySql data
I'm starting with python and trying to create linked comboboxes populate by MySql data where the second will be updated dynamically based on what is selected in the first.
The principle is simple you select a state in the first combo and the second must show you the list of all town of the selected state.
I found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252096/change-optionmenu-based-on-what-is-selected-in-another-optionmenu but I couldn't adapt it to my needs
Here's how I proceed:
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector

mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
    host="myhost",
    user="my_user",
    passwd="my_pass",
    database="erp_gir"
)
conn=mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

def listOfState():
    qSallState = 'SELECT DISTINCT stateName FROM state;'
    conn.execute(qSallState)
    stateQR = conn.fetchall()
    states = [s[0] for s in stateQR]
    return states

def townOfState(*args):
    qSallTownOfState = 'SELECT DISTINCT townName, stateCode FROM town as t JOIN state as s ON s.stateId = t.townState WHERE s.stateName = '+stateBox.get()+';'
    conn.execute(qSallTownOfState)
    townsQR = conn.fetchall()
    towns = [t[0] for t in townsQR]
    return towns

root = tk.Tk()

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

stateSelected = tk.StringVar()
stateSelected.set("")

stateBox = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=stateSelected, values=listOfState())
stateBox.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky='ew')
stateBox.current(0)
stateBox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", townOfState())

townBox = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable='', values=townOfState())
townBox.grid(row=4,column=0, sticky='ew')

#stateSelected.trace('w',townOfState)


root.mainloop()

Whether using the bind method or trace I always get an error and I don't know how to get out of it.
The errors:

line 41, in <module>
townOfState = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable='', values=townOfState())
line 23, in townOfState
conn.execute(qSallTownOfState)
~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

